# JPanel and GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I would like to dynamically place buttons in a JPanel. For that, I chose to apply a GridBagLayout to this panel (the one to contain the buttons).

the problem is that my buttons appear from the center of my panel while I would like them to be placed from top to bottom.

here is my code:

```
void placerListeUsers(){

  jPanel49.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  //jPanel49 est le panel sur lequel je place mes boutons.
  //jPanel49 est placé dans une JScrollPane
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  //c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

  c.weightx = 1;
  //c.weighty = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
  c.gridy = i;
  jPanel49.add(new JButton("Super"), c);

}
```

and what he produces:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vBQj.png]

thank you for helping me fix this problem

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the code. So you need the frame containing the panel. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code to verify your results and see exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that my buttons appear from the center of my panel while I would like them to be placed from top to bottom.

You need to specify weightx/y constraints, otherwise the components gather in the middle.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The section on [Specifying Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagConstraints) will give you more information.

It looks to me like you just have vertical buttons. Maybe a `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` added to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` of the frame would be easier.

Comment: thank you for answering my question.
I do not see how to put 2 layout in the same JPanel.
can you help me with a piece of code?

Comment: I never suggested to add 2 layouts in the same panel. I can't help with your code because you didn't post your [mcve] showing the problem. You were asked to post the `MCVE` 15 hours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did not provide a MCVE as requested. I try to provide a solution for your layout... ;)

The problem is, as already mentioned by camickr, you need to tell GridBagLayout where to put all the extra space of your Panel after calculating the size of the buttons:

- **anchor** has to be GridBagConstraints.NORTH.
- **weighty** needs to be set to 1 for the last button added to your panel.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();

  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          System.exit(0);
      }
  });
  Container content = frame.getContentPane();
  GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
  c.weightx = 1;
  int buttonCount = 5;
  for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
      c.weighty = i == buttonCount - 1 ? 1 : 0;
      c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
      c.gridy = i;
      JButton button = new JButton("Super");
      panel.add(button, c);
  }
  content.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
  frame.pack();
  frame.setSize(400, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  ```